# Why is my Mac beeping at me in a Sprint-Nextel-PTT kind of way?

Tags: mac, audio, osx-snow-leopard

I'm really stumped about this one. Before on OSX 10.5 and now on OSX 10.6, my Mac occasionally beeps at me. It's a split-second "bee-bee-beep" that sounds vaguely similar to the push-to-talk beep you hear on Sprint/Nextel PTT commercials. I haven't been able to isolate what's running when it happens or what happens before it happens. Possible culprits are Quicksilver, Firefox, DropBox, Evernote helper, TrueCrypt, Wally.

PS I'm starting to wonder if Greasemonkey for Firefox could be the culprit.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Chrome for a long time but all the same other apps and problem hasn't occurred. I'm chalking it up to FF w/ Greasemonkey until further notice.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not listed in your "possible culprits" lineup, but are you using TweetDeck? That program alerts with a sound similar to the Nextel PTT alert (both of which I find terribly annoying).

If TD is indeed the cause, you can disable its sounds [like so](http://support.tweetdeck.com/entries/94538-how-can-i-turn-off-sound-notifications-for-one-of-my-twitter-accounts):

> Go to Settings -> Notifications and click 'Advanced Options for columns'. This will bring up individual settings for each column you currently have loaded. Find the column (Twitter account names will be in parentheses after the column name) for the Twitter account you want to disable notifications for and uncheck what you want to turn off.